# pip3 - Python 3.6.3 having pip only

Tags: python3

hi I have pip installed on my python but I need to install some packages that require pip3, I couldnt change pip to pip3.

an ideas?
Kay

Comment: did you install pip3?

Answer (score 2):

`sudo apt-get install python3-pip`

But note that Python2 and Python3 are completely independent of one another; installing a package in one does not install it into the other.